# How to specify "updatepolicy" for Gradle-build using mavenLocal()

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle, nexus

I am using Gradle as build tool for my projects. Besides my local development computer there is a Nexus repository manager caching packages from Maven Central (and others) as well as local release- and SNAPSHOT-builds, which are published at least daily by Jenkins CI.

In `build.gradle` I have the following definition of repos:

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  maven { url http://url.to.nexus:8081/nexus/... }
  flatDir {
    ...
  }
}
```

The project (`A`) references several internal libraries (e.g. `B`) - also in SNAPSHOT versions. If I build `A`, the referenced SNAPSHOT-version of `B` is fetched from Nexus since there is no version in `mavenLocal` and Jenkins published the desired version - so everything is fine.

If I change some things in `B` and want to use immediately in `A`, I build/install `B` locally (using `gradle install`) and the current SNAPSHOT goes into `mavenLocal` making it available for the build of `A`.
But from this time, the library `B` is **always** fetched from `mavenLocal`. Even if after some time a colleague changes `B` and there is a newer SNAPSHOT version available on Nexus it won't be used.

Using Maven it would be possible to specify an `updatePolicy` like `daily` (which is also the default) solving the problem. But I don't see a way how to do this in Gradle (except purging `~/.m2/repository` once per day).

**== UPDATE ==**

According to the comment of jlb, I would like to add:

I don't have any repositories defined in the Maven-settings since dependency-resolution and artifact download are completely managed by gradle. So all repositories are only defined in the Gradle's build scripts.
Using the local Maven-repository is just an (often recommended) workaround in order to use local (intermediate) builds of libs in other projects without the need to publish them every time to some repository manager. IMO this is essential when extending libraries (`B` in the example above).

In addition, this only works if the order of the repository is defined as stated above. If an artifact of the same snapshot-version exists on a repository, further repos will not be checked, even if there might be newer (snapshot)-builds available there.

Comment: If you want control over when to refresh dependencies, `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies <task>` will do that when needed; the default update logic will apply without this option. Should work with `gradle` instead of `./gradlew` in the same manner.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-get-gradle-to-download-newer-snapshots-to-gradle-cache-when-using-an-ivy-repository/7344

> Since SNAPSHOTs are a Maven concept, they aren't treated as anything
>   special in an 'ivy' repository. Unfortunately, there's not (yet) any
>   way to specify a custom pattern for a 'maven' repository, so you're a
>   bit stuck.
>
> The best way to tell Gradle to check for updated versions of a
>   dependency is to flag the dependency as 'changing'. Gradle will then
>   check for updates every 24 hours, but this can be configured using the
>   resolutionStrategy DSL.
>
> ```
> configurations.all {
>     // check for updates every build
>     resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
> }
>   dependencies {
>     compile group: "group", name: "projectA", version: "1.1-SNAPSHOT", changing: true
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>[from gradle doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) point 23.6.3 explains that graddle will look for your maven settings.xml 
Try to define the update policy in $user_home/.m2/settings.xml Define your remote repositroy there and set the update policy to "always" https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories</strike>

also point 23.7 explains the rules from dependencies resolution :

> Given a required dependency, Gradle first attempts to resolve the module for that dependency. Each repository is inspected in order, searching first for a module descriptor file (POM or Ivy file) that indicates the presence of that module

among other things
 Stupid question here: have you tried to define mavenLocal() after your custom repo, so that the build searches first for new dependencies there before looking in your local repo ?

```
   repositories {    
       maven { url http://url.to.nexus:8081/nexus/... }
          ...
       }
       mavenLocal()
   }
```

Ok so I ran into this issue today, and I found [this](http://asoftwareguy.com/2013/10/25/grails-2-3-maven-dependency-caching-issues/) . I tried and it downloaded the new plugin version into my local repo. Did not have time to read thoroughly the link, but that work with (gradle 2.5.3)

```
mavenRepo ("http://my.server/repos/my-grails-plugins") {
    updatePolicy 'always'
}
```

and using

```
grails compile --stacktrace --verbose --refresh-dependencies
```

So, there's that

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added some additional information in the update-section.

Comment: I actually ran into the exact same issue today, and I found that http://asoftwareguy.com/2013/10/25/grails-2-3-maven-dependency-caching-issues/  . It seems to work, so I will edit my answer